# Ion-propelled device ionization

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, propulsion, ionization-energy

Imagine we have an ion-propelled device: [image]

Lower part is made of 1cm wide aluminum foil, upper part is separated from it with 3cm gap and made of 0.1mm copper wire. Parts are connected to high-voltage current source and act as cathode and anode. When voltage reaches 19kV, wire starts to ionize air molecules around it, and they travel towards foil, where they then deionize. Neutral air molecules are getting carried away with these ions, which causes air flow strong enough to lift the device.

Question: is there any amount of ions that leave cathode-anode system? If they carry neutral monecules with them, might they get carried away from device by these air molecules as well? If yes, then how much, and how to calculate this amount based on parameters of the device?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, you already know that ions leave the system, and yet you are asking if ions are leaving the system. Maybe you can be a lot more specific on what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I probably should specify: after some air molecules get ionized on wire and travel towards foil, they deionize on it. Question is, do they all deionize on foil, or some slip away, and if they do, then how many?